# Pulling Fiber Optic Cable

Tags: fiber

Someone who has a lot of experience with fiber optic cable told me that somehow the cable needs to be pushed through conduits rather than pulled like I would with a Cat 6. Is this true? If so, what is the best way to push the cable through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's less of an issue with multimode or large bundles of fibres but yes, for single mode fibres it can make a lot of sense to 'blow not suck', the way it's usually done is to attach the end/s of the fibres to some form of baffle that almost completely blocks the air on all sides of the conduit and then it's simply blown up the conduit. Think of it a bit like a blow-pipe.

Comment: If I buy just a simple 100m pre-terminated fiber cable, wrapped the LC connector with something to protect it and then pushed it with a cable snake, do you think that would work OK? I'm pretty certain my conduit has a hole in it, so I'm not sure I can blow something through. Thanks!

Comment: Reckon you'd be fine but buy a spare cable just in case.

Comment: I always used a plastic grocery bag and a shop vac.

Answer (score 1):

Push Pull control cables are the most reliable means of transferring motion. They are available in various mounting configurations, travel or stroke length, overall length and temperature options.

3 Series Push-Pull (Rods 10-32 or M5-0.8)

4 Series Push-Pull (Rods 1/4-28 or M6-1.0)

6 Series Push-Pull (Rods 5/16-24 or M8-1.25)

8 Series Push-Pull (Rods 3/8-24 or M10-1.5)

If further assistance is required let me know.